# Use cas server without overlay

Tags: cas

I want to use cas server without overlay, this is my attempt.
I get classnotfound: org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication when compiling, but it is already in the dependency(cas-server-webapp-init). Class.forname works fine, but i want to know how to use cas without overlay

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class CasServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication.main(args);
        /* But the following code works fine
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication");
        Method method = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        method.invoke(null, (Object) args);
         */
    }
}
```

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>cas-server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-boot.version>2.5.4</spring-boot.version>
        <cas.version>6.4.5</cas.version>
        <log4j.version>2.17.1</log4j.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
... spring-boot, log4j, cas-server-support-bom
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp-init-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-core-web-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-core-util-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the required cas core dependencies, you can directly name the class you created (i.e. SpringApplication.run(CasServerApplication.class, args)) instead of CasWebApplication in the entrypoint class.

Just like you, I wanted to use the cas server without overlay-template and I have created an alternative template. You can check out from https://github.com/dgempiuc/cas-template